# The "table" in sqlContext.table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working my way through a book on Spark and I'm on a section dealing with the join method for dataframes. In this example, the "trips" table is being joined with the "stations" table:

```
trips = sqlContext.table("trips")
stations = sqlContext.table("stations")
joined = trips.join(stations, trips.start_terminal == stations.station_id)
joined.printSchema()
```

The data is supposed to come from two spreadsheets, trips.csv and stations.csv, but I don't know how Spark is supposed to figure that out. It seems to me that there should be a line indicating where "trips" and "stations" are supposed to come from.

If I try something like

```
trips = sqlContext.table('/home/l_preamble/Documents/trips.csv')
```

it doesn't like it "pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nextraneous input '/' expecting {'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD'..."

So how can I point it in the direction of the data? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to join two dataframes in pyspark, you should try this:-

```
df1=sqlContext.registerTempTable("trips")
df2=sqlContext.registerTempTable("stations")

df2.join(df1,['column_name'],outer)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, maybe you need this

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('MyApp').getOrCreate()
df_trips = spark.read.load(path='/home/l_preamble/Documents/trips.csv', format='csv', sep=',')
df_trips.createOrReplaceTempView('trips')
result = spark.sql("""select * from trips""")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did get an error, but I realized that the supplied files don't have any headers in them (like start_terminal or station_id). I'm starting to think that this book is kind of garbage.

Comment: @lengthy_preamble what is this book you've mentioned ?

Comment: @eliasah it's Sam's Teach Yourself Apache Spark in 24 Hours. It's not bad, but there are many parts where the author leaps to stuff without explaining how to get there. It's also written for Spark 1.x, but that's the way it goes with technology sometimes.